# Pytorch resume from checkpoint in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, ckpt

I'm running a pytroch model that has already been written. In that code authors save checkpoints (ckpt) files each epoch. But the authors didn't give any option to resume the training from one of this checkpoints. Here is the authors original code.

```py
trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(args,
                                            default_root_dir=args.logdir,
                                            gpus = args.gpus,
                                            accelerator='ddp',
                                            sync_batchnorm=True,
                                            plugins=DDPPlugin(find_unused_parameters=False),
                                            profiler='simple',
                                            benchmark=True,
                                            log_every_n_steps=1,
                                            flush_logs_every_n_steps=5,
                                            callbacks=[checkpoint_callback,
                                                        ],
                                            check_val_every_n_epoch = args.val_every,
                                            max_epochs = args.epochs,
                                            logger=logger
                                            )
```

So I changed the above code to start running from a given checkpoint using command line arguments. Here is what I have done.

```py
if args.loadfromcheckpoint>0:
        trainer = pl.Trainer(
            resume_from_checkpoint=args.logdir+"/epoch={checkpoint}-last.ckpt".format(checkpoint=args.loadfromcheckpoint),
            default_root_dir=args.logdir,
            gpus = args.gpus,
            accelerator='ddp',
            sync_batchnorm=True,
            plugins=DDPPlugin(find_unused_parameters=False),
            profiler='simple',
            benchmark=True,
            log_every_n_steps=1,
            flush_logs_every_n_steps=5,
            callbacks=[checkpoint_callback,
                        ],
            check_val_every_n_epoch = args.val_every,
            max_epochs = args.epochs,
            logger=logger)
        trainer.fit(TCP_model, dataloader_train, dataloader_val)
    else:
        trainer.fit(TCP_model, dataloader_train, dataloader_val)
```

The above code works fine.
Since I'm quite new to Pytorch and Pytorch Lightning I have following questions,

1. Does the lightning API only restore state_dict or does it restore all such as optimzer_states, lr_schedulers as well.
2. If lightning doesn't load all those, how to load those states manually.

Comment: see https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/discussions/11378

Comment: Thanks, this helped with the problem I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightning API will load everything - the entire training state at a particular epoch, the model's state_dict, optimizer's and scheduler's state_dict if you use `resume_from_checkpoint`. If you just want to do quick evaluation by only using model's state_dict, use `load_from_checkpoint`

Comment: This is what the lightning API prints on the console when you start training by resuming from a checkpoint

"Restored all states from the checkpoint at checkpoint_abc.ckpt"

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the problem with the help of the GitHub link provided in the comment in the question.

Comment: @RushirajParmar Does it load also the `DataModule` the `model` was trained on?

Comment: @adosar No, it won't load any data module